# May the name of a macro parameter be a keyword?

Tags: c, macros, keyword

I discovered something interesting while writing code. I defined a macro in my code and accidentally used the keyword `int` as the variable name of parameter of that macro. The code worked perfectly fine, but I’m a bit surprised about it. I have read that in C keywords are reserved words and cannot be used as variable names.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT(int) printf("%d",int)

int main()
{
    int x=2;
    PRINT(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain me why is it working fine? Is it not true that keywords are reserved and cannot be used as variable names in C, or is this some exception in C for macros?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, `int` is not a variable (more correct: *parameter*) name because of course `PRINT` is also not a function -- it's a preprocessor macro.

Whatever you write as part of a macro definition is only looked at by the preprocessor. By the time the compiler gets to see the processed source nothing remains of the `"int"` name.

This is similar to what happens with formal parameters of functions: the compiler gets to see those names, but after it's done with the source no trace of them remains in the compiled code (so you need to load debug symbols in the debugger to "get this information back").

Comment: It means I can use any keyword in macro and it will work fine,right ? Is this thing valid for only macros in C ?

Comment: @dark_shadow: The preprocessor does not know about C, so as far as it is concerned there *are* no keywords (so yes, you can use anything). It's valid in C and in C++.

Answer (score 4):

The `#define` is replaced by the preprocessor before the C compiler ever sees it. What the compiler itself sees is this:

```
int main()
{
int x=2;
printf("%s",x);
return 0;
}
```

This is valid C code. Using a keyword as a variable name does give an error:

```
int main()
{
int float=2;
printf("%s",float);
return 0;
}
```

This will not compile.

Answer (score 3):

During the preprocessing phases, keywords do not exist and are just seen as ordinary identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

C standard section 5.1.1.2 defines nine phases of C translation. Preprocessing phase is number 4; keywords are recognized as such only in the phase 7; before that phase all keywords are considered regular *preprocessing tokens*. See [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) for further details.

> keyword: one of
> auto break case [...]
>
> The above tokens (case sensitive) are reserved (in translation phases 7 and 8) for use as
> keywords, and shall not be used otherwise.

Comment: But you're linking to a C++ standard.

Comment: @cnicutar You're right! I fixed the link and updated the section number.

Comment: A small addition, the C++ standard, but not the C one, explicitly doesn't allow to define macro with names _lexically identical to keywords_ when including standard headers.